# Hot to capture Selenium WebDriver exception using Python Interactive Window in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, exception, try-catch

I receive the Selenium exception **NoSuchElementException** though I have a try except block.
Here is a reduced version of the code, the stack trace indicates that it is the WebDriverWait line that is causing the Exception:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import (TimeoutException,NoSuchElementException)

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://example.com")

all_rows = []
for row in all_rows:
    row.find_element(By.XPATH, './/td[3]').click()
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text() = 'Close']")))
        # wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text() = 'Close']")))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

In debugging options under 'Breakpoints', 'Raised Exceptions' is unticked.

Comment: Post the relevant html or url. To look at the error message. It seems some row it doesn’t have the column 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to presented here code, the exception can be cause by `row.find_element(By.XPATH, './/td[3]').click()` code line.
This line is not inside the `try` block now.
If so, you can simply move it into the `try` block, as following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import (TimeoutException,NoSuchElementException)

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://example.com")

all_rows = []
for row in all_rows:    
    try:
        row.find_element(By.XPATH, './/td[3]').click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text() = 'Close']")))
        # wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text() = 'Close']")))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, the stack trace indicates that it is the WebDriverWait line that is causing the Exception. Should the stack trace not be trusted?

Comment: `WebDriverWait` throws `TimeoutException` in case the specified expected condition was not found till the defined timeout. In will never throw `NoSuchElementException` exception. While `find_element` is throwing such exception in case if could find element matching the passed locator.

Comment: For others who find this:
The interactive window indicated a 'TimeoutException', but opening the full output data in a text editor showed the NoSuchElementException.